# how do I add loader on tab click

Tags: loader, jpreloader

could anyone help me adding this for navigating threw tabs. I want it to have some kind of loader just for the look.

http://jsfiddle.net/3KAnM/33/ loader

tabs example:

```
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#north-america" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-globe"></i>  <span>NORTH AMERICA</span></a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#europe" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-globe"></i>  <span>EUROPE</span></a></li>
                <li role="presentation" class="unverifiedna"><a href="#unverifiedna" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-globe"></i>  <span>NA UNVERIFIED</span></a></li>
                <li role="presentation" class="unverifiedeuw"><a href="#unverifiedeuw" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-globe"></i>  <span>EUW UNVERIFIED</span></a></li>
                <li role="presentation" class="pbe"><a href="#pbe" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-globe"></i>  <span>PBE</span></a></li>
```

Comment: If you give it a go and hit a problem then post it here, but this is way too vague for anyone to be able to help with.

Comment: I did try to insert it between but the spinner just spins non stop, sorry I'm new with this